# How can I break up a long string to multiple lines?

Tags: php, html, string

I am estimating the value of Pi and as everyone knows it doesn't have an end.  But I want to print my estimate to say, 100 significant figures.

My problem is that when I print it it just pushes out the edge of my webpage.  It's being printed within a `<div>` and also ignores the edge of it.

I don't have access to the value as it is being constantly updated so I can't just add some `\n`.

Can I make it drop to a new line when required?

Comment: What format is the output in?

Comment: Sorry, I just editted it to say.
It's being printed onto a webpage.

Comment: is your question about html / css / or php?

Comment: I guess it's more CSS than anything, sorry.

Comment: why don't you just use <div sytle="overflow:hidden" or overflow:auto;? if you break the number anyway, you cant copy and paste it easy if this should be featured later ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably looking for [`wordwrap()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php). Just say after how many characters you want to break it with a string, e.g.

```
$pi = "3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939";
echo wordwrap($pi, 10, "<br>", TRUE);
```

output:

```
3.14159265
3589793238
4626433832
7950288419
716939
```

Comment: This is perfect!  Exactly what I wanted.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use css3, add this to your div:

```
word-wrap: break-word
```